# How to use Sync in ManytoMany and add statut to pivot table

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have three table and i'm in a many to many relationship.

Table "semaine"

```
id | name |
```

Table "bitheme"

```
id | namebitheme
```

Table "bitheme_semaine". In it i add a new "statut" columns

```
bitheme_id | semaine_id | statut
```

In my case I can have a status of 1 or 2 if the relationship exists (in database it"s 1 by defaut on this field).

In my edit form i have to checkbox :

```
<input type="checkbox" name="bithemes[]" value="{{ $id }}"> </input>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="statut[]" value="{{ $id }}"> </input>
```

I synchronize my table as well :

```
  $semaine->update($request->all());
    $semaine->bithemes()->sync($request->input('bithemes', []));
```

But i also want to synchronize the status if it is checked. 
So I added in the relationship of my Semaine model :

```
 public function bithemes()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Bitheme::class)->withPivot('statut');
}
```

and i try to test synchronize with :

```
$semaine->bithemes()->sync($request->input('bithemes', []), ['statut' => 2]);
```

But the statut is never synchronized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sync method takes as first parameter an `array` of IDs as in your example. But when you want to sync the attributes of the pivot table, give it an `array` with the IDs as `numeric index` of that array and an `array` as value of each index for the pivot attributes.

```
$syncable = [];
foreach($request->input('bithemes', []) as $bithemeId) {
    $syncable[$bithemeId] = ['status' => 2];
}
$semaine->bithemes()->sync($syncable);
```

For precision, the format you used is to sync only one ID

```
if (isset($request->input('bithemes')[0])) {
    $semaine->bithemes()->sync($request->input('bithemes')[0], ['statut' => 2]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perfect.
I changed my form with :

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="bithemes[]" value="{{ $id }}" {{ (in_array($id, old('bithemes', [])) || isset($semaine) && $semaine->bithemes->contains($id)) ? 'checked' : '' }}> </input>

                       <input type="checkbox" name="statut[]" value="{{ $id }}"> </input>
```

and my controller with :

```
 $syncable = [];
    foreach($request->input('bithemes', []) as $key => $value) {
        if (!isset ($request->input('statut')[$key])) {$statut = 1;} else {$statut = 2;}
        $syncable[$value] = ['statut' => $statut];
    }
    $semaine->bithemes()->sync($syncable);
```

and everything si fine now. Thanks